# append/prepend of JQuery creates an issue for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/engineerkhushal/yLpn2/2/).

I am trying to implement JQuerySwipe, in such a way that I have 1 scorebox Div for cricket match initiallly, On load I make 3 such div and scroll to second scorebox div and make it currentMatch. Now I want to scroll these 3 divs giving the impression of infinite divs by, scrolling Left and Right in such a way that if:

- I scroll in Left, First `div` should be remove and appended to
  `#matches`
- I scroll in Right, Last `div` should be remove and prepended to
  `#matches`
- Center `Div` should always be assigned currentMatch class so that I
  insert/modify currentMatch live status later.

Everything works fine but in last step When I remove first/last scorebox div and append/prepend it. It doesn't work, By not working I mean it gives a strange result, If I remove this last step my code works but then I won't be able to implement infinite scrolling.

Here is code for that circular list of scorebox divs:

```
/*Problem is here*/
debugger;
if (direction === "left") {
    var scorebox = '<div class = "scorebox" href="#scorecardtab">' + $(".scorebox:last").html() + '</div>';
    $("#matches").prepend(scorebox);
    $(".scorebox:last").remove();
}
else if (direction == "right") {
    var scorebox = '<div class = "scorebox" href="#scorecardtab">' + $(".scorebox:first").html() + '</div>';
    $("#matches").append(scorebox);
    $(".scorebox:first").remove();
}
```

**NOTE result just before statment `debugger;`, looks good there and then goes to hell, if anybody can help, thanks in advance.**

**Edit: There were some errors in jsfiddle, now current fiddle simulates my problem exactly. Problem Still there just simulated properly**

Comment: is two '==' for right and three '===' for left direction a typo?

Comment: thanks for noticing but it does not solve my problem :( @MandeepJain